# Is there any leak in NSAutoreleasepool?

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, pool, autorelease, nsautoreleasepool

What will be result ? is there any leak or crash??

```
-(NSString)returnPersonName {
NSAutorelease *pool = [[NSAutorelease alloc]init];
NSString *name = [[[NSString alloc]initWithString:@"Name"]autorelease];
[pool drain];
return name
}
```

bit confusing to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. This code violates memory management rules. You do `alloc`, so you get ownership of a +1 reference count, and then you do `autorelease` on it, by which you give up your ownership of the reference count. Therefore, you should not use `name` anymore, and it is not guaranteed to point to a valid object. You return it, a pointer to a potentially invalid object.
2. In this particular case, because of the implementation details of Cocoa, nothing "bad" will happen. The body of that function is equivalent to just `return @"Name";`. `@"Name"` is a string literal, and string literals are stored in static storage that exists for the entire lifetime of the program. That means those string objects are not subject to memory management -- `retain`, `release` on them have no effect. You do `[[NSString alloc] init...]` on it, but `NSString`'s initializers are optimized to simply retain and return its argument if the argument is already an immutable string. So you are not returning a new `NSString` object; you are just returning the same string literal which is statically allocated and not subject to memory management. Again, all this is implementation details of Cocoa that you cannot rely on.

Comment: So after going through your explanation I got confused with "string literals are stored in static storage that exists for the entire lifetime of the program" where as I am thinking as local variable whose life is with in {} of that function in which it declares, except using autorelease keyword. could you please explain this to me?  in using xcode 6.1 in Non ARC its print the name?? where is invalid object if uses autorelease and same time draining pool as well which will send release message to that object right? please, explain.

Comment: @Sandy: retain, release, autorelease, allocation, deallocation, etc are about memory management of objects. The variable holds a pointer to an object. Of course variables have scope, but the lifetime of a pointer variable has nothing to do with the lifetime or memory management of objects.

Answer (score 2):

I'm tipping the above could potentially crash because `[pool drain]` will cause **name** to be deallocated before it can be returned.

> In a reference-counted environment, the drain method behaves the same as release. Since an autorelease pool cannot be retained, this therefore causes the receiver to be deallocated. When an autorelease pool is deallocated, it sends a release message to all its autoreleased objects. If an object is added several times to the same pool, when the pool is deallocated it receives a release message for each time it was added.

The pool is not required, for something like this try -

```
-(NSString*)returnPersonName {
     NSString *name = [[[NSString alloc]initWithString:@"Name"]autorelease];
     return name;
     }
```

More info can be found in the [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1)

On a side note - an `@autorelease { }` pool block is better to use than **NSAutoreleasePool** and *even better* is switch to ARC!

Comment: using xcode 6.1 in Non ARC its print the name. here I am confused I was thinking same.

Comment: In this case, there will be no crash, because string literals are statically allocated, and not subject to memory management, and creating `NSString` on an immutable string will simply just return that immutable string.